# Coding a proper line-graph considering every year and country

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, plotly, plotly-python

I have a DataFrame made of 3 columns: 'Time' (years, from 1960 to 2022), 'Country' and 'GDP per capita'. For every year, there are load of countries representing its GDP per capita. I want to get, while using Python, a graph showing all the countries' GDP per capita through every year. Can someone help me in this duty?

At the beginning I used this code:

```
grouped_data = all_years_all_countries.groupby('Country Name')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,60))

for country, group in grouped_data:

    ax.plot(group['Time'].astype(str), group['GDP per capita'].astype(str), label=country)

ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('GDP per capita')
ax.set_title('GDP pc of European Countries Over Time')
ax.legend()
plt.show()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=GDP['Time'], y=GDP['GDP per capita']))
fig.update_layout(title='GDP per capita of countries per year', xaxis_title='Date', yaxis_title='GDP per capita')
fig.show()
```

However, I would like to output a graph like the following code (It lacks the output of countries):

```
fig = go.Figure() 
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=GDP['Time'], y=GDP['GDP per capita'])) 
fig.update_layout(title='GDP per capita of countries per year', xaxis_title='Date', yaxis_title='GDP per capita') 
fig.show()
```

I thought about getting something like the first code, but adding another line that allows me to show the country that represents every line when clicking on the line.

Can someone help me in this task? Thank you.

Comment: Why you tagged [plotly] your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear to me what you want to do, as it is lacking some representative data to work with.
However, does this do what you want?

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(GDP,x='Time', y='GDP per capita', color='Country name')) 
fig.update_layout(title='GDP per capita of countries per year', xaxis_title='Date', yaxis_title='GDP per capita') 
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
# we want to plot a few curves, we need matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# if I understand, the following is "like" your real data:
#   a label, a year and a value — comma separated
data = 'A,2012,7\nB,2014,4\nA,2014,5\nA,2011,6\nB,2012,8\nB,2011,9'

# the following is an idiomatic way to group the data points
# according to the labels — note converting year and value to integers
d = {}
for label, *yv in (line.split(',') for line in data.splitlines()):
    d.setdefault(label, []).append([int(n) for n in yv])

# loop over labels, plotting the transposed "zip(*" and sorted list
for label, list_yv in d.items():
    plt.plot(*zip(*sorted(list_yv)), '-*', label=label)

# fix the tick position on time axis
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1.0))

# the legend, and show the result
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```